# WebDriver element found, but click returns nothing

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, selenium

I couldn't find a solution in existing posts (though I have been looking). I am trying to scrape data from the URL in the code after making selections in the drop-down menu. In the end, I would like to click on the save button and download the excel file. Here is the code which works fine, but does not end up clicking on the save button.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


url = 'http://omms.nic.in/#'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
```

This clicks on the 'Progress Monitoring' item in the menu and then clicks on 'Physical and Financial Project Summary' item. Then I make a selection for each drop-down item.

```
progElem = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Progress Monitoring').click()
summElem = browser.find_element_by_link_text("Physical and Financial Project 
Summary").click()

browser.implicitly_wait(10)

#select the state
stateElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='StateCode']")
state_select = Select(stateElem)
ap = state_select.select_by_visible_text('Andhra Pradesh')

#select the district
distElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='DistrictCode']")
dist_select = Select(distElem)
dist = dist_select.select_by_visible_text('All Districts')

#select the block
blockElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='BlockCode']")
block_select = Select(blockElem)
block = block_select.select_by_visible_text('All Blocks')

#select the year
yearElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='Year']")
year_select = Select(yearElem)
year = year_select.select_by_visible_text('2016-2017')

#select the batch
batchElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='Batch']")
batch_select = Select(batchElem)
batch = batch_select.select_by_visible_text('All Batches')

#select the funding agency
collabElem = 
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='FundingAgency']")
collab_select = Select(collabElem)
collab = collab_select.select_by_visible_text('Regular PMGSY')

# check the roadwise box
checkElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='RoadWise']")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", checkElem)

# click on the view button
viewElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='button']")
viewElem.click()

#switch to a new frame
browser.switch_to_frame(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe"))
WebDriverWait(browser, 40).until( 
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//table[@title='Export drop down 
menu']")))
saveElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@title='Export drop down 
menu']")
saveElem.click()

#excelElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='Excel']")
#excelElem.click()
#browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", excelElem)
```

The code runs successfully, however, does not click on the save button. Surprisingly, once I run the code in my spyder editor. And then type saveElem.click() in the IPython shell the button gets clicked.

I am too much a beginner to understand what is going on.

Comment: Hi! How is going?

Comment: @Ratmir. First thanks for answering my questions earlier. I am trying to run a loop for different selections for 'State'. However, in the loop sometimes the 'Road Wise' box remains unchecked. I tried various things (e.g., time.sleep(10) and WebDriverWait), but to no avail. Other than the loop and a few other minor changes I am using the above code. Do you have any thoughts? I could submit the new code, but dont want to replace the original code.

Comment: It should be a separate question.

Comment: Thanks @RatmirAsanov. I asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48814291/selenium-webdriver-click-skips-some-check-boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
browser.get("http://omms.nic.in")

progElem = browser.find_element_by_link_text("Progress Monitoring").click()
summElem = browser.find_element_by_link_text("Physical and Financial Project Summary").click()

# Select the state.
stateElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='StateCode']")
state_select = Select(stateElem).select_by_visible_text("Andhra Pradesh")

# Select the district.
distElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='DistrictCode']")
dist_select = Select(distElem).select_by_visible_text("All Districts")

# Select the block.
blockElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='BlockCode']")
block_select = Select(blockElem).select_by_visible_text("All Blocks")

# Select the year.
yearElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='Year']")
year_select = Select(yearElem).select_by_visible_text("2016-2017")

# Select the batch.
batchElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='Batch']")
batch_select = Select(batchElem).select_by_visible_text("All Batches")

# Select the funding agency.
collabElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='FundingAgency']")
collab_select = Select(collabElem).select_by_visible_text("Regular PMGSY")

# Check the road wise box.
checkElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='RoadWise']")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", checkElem)

# Click on the view button.
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='button']").click()

time.sleep(5)

# Switch to a new frame.
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe"))

# Click on the "Excel" button.
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Export drop down menu']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div/a[@title='Excel']"))).click()

# Switch back to the main content.
browser.switch_to.default_content()

time.sleep(5)

browser.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks Ratmir for the response. Unfortunately, the same thing happens. The code runs successfully without the save button getting clicked.

Comment: Thanks Ratmir, that works great. If you don't mind answering, I had a few questions. 1) was it time.sleep(5) that got it working. If yes, shouldn't WebDriverWait have taken care of the delay in loading? 2) In your original comment you also suggested to change the XPATH of the Export Drop Down Menu button. Was my original XPATH wrong? How could have I known or is it by trial and error? Thanks much for answering my extended questions. Best!!!

Comment: @Yogesh, if my answer was helpful -- check a tick near my answer, please.

Comment: 1) Yes, the first `time.sleep(5)` was helpful, but you can use `WebDriverWait` for the appearance of the frame. 2) Yes, your XPath was wrong. You need to be clicked on the link. Hope it helps you!