# Selenium WebDriver Click skips some checkboxes

Tags: python, selenium, checkbox, drop-down-menu

This is a follow-up question to this:

[WebDriver element found, but click returns nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48602367/webdriver-element-found-but-click-returns-nothing?noredirect=1#comment84608392_48602367)

I am trying to scrape data from the URL in the code after making selections in the drop-down menu. I first click on Progress Monitoring and then Physical and Financial Project Summary. Then I make the following selections: State, District, Block, Year, Batch, and Collaboration. I would also like to check the Road Wise button and then click on the view button. After the table loads, I would like to click on the save button and download the excel file. In the code below I also loop through different selections under "State" item. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import os


chromedriver = r"C:\Users\yuppal\chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
browser.get("http://omms.nic.in")
browser.maximize_window()

#Click on the item Progress Monitoring
progElem = browser.find_element_by_link_text("Progress Monitoring").click()
#Click on the item Physical and Financial Project Sumamry
summElem = browser.find_element_by_link_text("Physical and Financial Project Summary").click()

#Find the element for state and create a list of different selection options    
stateElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='StateCode']")
state_options = stateElem.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")

#delete the first option in the list
del state_options[0]

def select_option(xpath, text):
    '''
    This function will select the remaining dropd-down menu items. 
    '''
    elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    Select(elem).select_by_visible_text(text)

#run the loop for each option in the list of states
for option in state_options:

        select_state = Select(stateElem).select_by_value(option.get_attribute("value"))
        # Select the district.
        select_option("//select[@name='DistrictCode']","All Districts")   
        # Select the block.
        select_option("//select[@name='BlockCode']","All Blocks")   
        # Select the year.
        select_option("//select[@name='Year']","All Years")
        # Select the batch.
        select_option("//select[@name='Batch']","All Batches")
        # Select the funding agency.
        select_option("//select[@name='FundingAgency']","Regular PMGSY")

        # Check the road wise box.
        time.sleep(10)
        checkElem = WebDriverWait(browser, 120).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@title='Road Wise']")))
        browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", checkElem)

        # Click on the view button.
        time.sleep(10)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='button']").click()



        # Switch to a new frame.
        time.sleep(10)
        frame = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='loadReport']/iframe")
        browser.switch_to.default_content()
        #browser.switch_to.frame(frame)
        WebDriverWait(browser, 120).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(frame))
        #browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='loadReport']/iframe"))

        # click on the save button
        time.sleep(10)
        WebDriverWait(browser, 120).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Export drop down menu']"))).click()

        # Within the save button, Click on the "Excel" option.
        time.sleep(10)
        WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div/a[@title='Excel']"))).click()


        # Switch back to the main content.
        time.sleep(20)
        browser.switch_to.default_content()
```

My issue is the "Road Wise" checkbox gets clicked only for some states. Thus the loop proceeds without clicking the checkbox for some states. I checked the HTML code and it is the same for all checkboxes.

I thought the problem might be that the "View" button gets clicked before the road wise button is clickable. So I put some waiting period before both road wise and view buttons. But that doesn't seem to help. So I can't really understand why the checkbox button isn't clicked for some iterations in the loop.

Comment: Could you please post steps? What you what to do? Thanks.

Comment: This sounds so specific to your case, I'm having a hard time knowing how I would figure this out without stepping through the debugger with the site right in front of me. It probably has something to do with how the website itself is functioning, which I'm sure is hard to put details about here.

Comment: @RatmirAsanov I edited the code. I am not sure if it gives you more info about what I want to do. But hope it helps. Thanks!

Comment: @mrfreester,  I believe it is not specific to the website. But yes I am not sure.

Comment: @Yogesh my best guess without knowing some more details about the site is that your script clicks the check box, and then some script or ajax thing completes which refreshes the checkbox to be unclicked, but by then your script has moved on. You mentioned you've tried putting waits in front of the road wise click which should get around that though. Do the check boxes still get missed when you step through with the debugger?

Comment: @mrfreester, thanks for your comment. I have never used a debugger. I will read on how to use one and see what happens. Strangely when I run the script (without a loop) for the problem states (where the box was not checked in the loop), it works fine. Something happens when I iterate for each state in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before clicking on the checkbox, check that is already selected or not:

```
# Check the road wise box.
time.sleep(10)
checkElem = WebDriverWait(browser, 120).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@title='Road Wise']")))

if checkElem.is_selected() != True:

    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", checkElem)
```

PS: In your case, the click will be only in the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: Ratmir, that works great. Thanks for your help again!